# Mount SFTP server?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mount, sftp

I seem to be able to add a network adress or FTP server directly in Windows explorer. It can't handle SFTP though. I know about Filezille, but there I can just access the server, not mount it. I need to mount it because I want to be able to access those files from programes on my computer, and not have to copy them around all the time.

Comment: Sounds like a software recommendation to me.... See https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/38457/mount-sftp-on-windows but I'd suggest playing with WinSCP if you can. I've never mounted SFTP with it but I've automated many FTP related processes over the years and know it's good and helpful for retaining many defined connections.